# Does SmartSheet support any CURL to get the total row count in a sheet?

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

I am using curl with REST to access Smartshets in my C# running on WIN CE. My application is supposed to dump some data on smartsheet periodically.

Before I write to a sheet, I would like to know the total row count in the sheet so that I don't exceed 5000 rows per sheet.

I am looking for an API that would return just row count given the sheet id?

Currently using below API which returns the entire sheet data and takes very long to fetch and format.
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}

with data of upto 5000 rows pr sheet, it takes very long to fetch and format below response to determine the available rows:

```
{
  "id": 4583173393803140,
  "name": "sheet 1",
  "version": 6,
  "totalRowCount": 240,
  "accessLevel": "OWNER",
  "effectiveAttachmentOptions": [
    "EVERNOTE",
    "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
    "EGNYTE",
    "FILE",
    "ONEDRIVE",
    "DROPBOX",
    "BOX_COM"
  ],
  "readOnly": true,
  "ganttEnabled": true,
  "dependenciesEnabled": true,
  "resourceManagementEnabled": true,
  "cellImageUploadEnabled": true,
  "userSettings": {
    "criticalPathEnabled": false,
    "displaySummaryTasks": true
  },
  "userPermissions": {
    "summaryPermissions": "ADMIN"
  },
  "workspace": {
    "id": 825898975642500,
    "name": "New Workspace"
  },
  "projectSettings": {
    "workingDays": [
      "MONDAY",
      "TUESDAY",
      "WEDNESDAY"
    ],
    "nonWorkingDays": [],
    "lengthOfDay": 8
  },
  "hasSummaryFields": false,
  "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/b/home?lx=pWNSDH9itjBXxBzFmyf-5w",
  "createdAt": "2018-09-24T20:27:57Z",
  "modifiedAt": "2018-09-26T20:45:08Z",
  "columns": [
    {
      "id": 4583173393803140,
      "version": 0,
      "index": 0,
      "primary": true,
      "title": "Primary Column",
      "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
      "validation": false
    },
    {
      "id": 2331373580117892,
      "version": 0,
      "index": 1,
      "options": [
        "new",
        "in progress",
        "completed"
      ],
      "title": "status",
      "type": "PICKLIST",
      "validation": true
    }
  ],
  "rows": Array[4962]....
}
```

Any help will b greatly appreciated.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a request to specifically return the number of rows on a `Sheet`. But, with any `GET /sheets/{sheetId}` operation the resulting `Sheet` object returned will have a top level `totalRowCount` attribute on it. So, you don't have to `GET` the sheet and count the objects in the `rows` array. Instead you can look to the `totalRowCount` attribute and the value there to know how many rows are currently on the sheet.

If you are concerned about pulling down all of the `Sheet` data you can use [paging](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#paging) to keep from getting all of the data returned. Doing a `GET /sheets/{sheetId}?pageSize=1` will give you the `Sheet` object with only the first row of data to help make the payload smaller. The `totalRowCount` attribute will still be present in the response.